# Surrounding background color in Meteor JS

Tags: meteor

So I am working in Meteor JS for the first time.
I've set up my templates in a pretty basic fasion, and I have all of them wrapped up in a container div. My question is how to change the color of the rest of the screen, that is on the left and right side from that container. For styling I'm using materializecss. I have no idea how to approach this at the moment. The code I'm using is below.

```
<head>
  <title>Waste manager</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="cyan">

</div>
</body>

<template name='ApplicationLayout'>
  {{> yield "navbar"}}
  {{> yield "main"}}
  {{> yield "addForm"}}
  {{> yield "footer"}}
</template>


<!-- <template name="note">
  <li class="collection-item">
    {{text}}
    <a href="#" class="delete-note secondary-content"><button class="brand-logo">delete</button></a>
  </li>
</template>-->

<template name="navbar">
  <div class="container">
  <nav class="cyan">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="/" class="brand-logo hide-on-med-and-down">Waste Manager</a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/maps" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light green"><i class="material-icons left">map</i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="/cards" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light green"><i class="material-icons left">info</i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            {{> loginButtons}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="addForm">
  <div class="container">
  <form class="add-form">
      <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Input text">
  </form>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="maps">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([18.41, 43.85]),
          zoom: 12
        })
      });

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector;

  var marker = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
      ol.proj.fromLonLat([18.4165, 43.8594])
    ),
  });
  vectorSource.addFeature (marker);

  var marker2 = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
      ol.proj.fromLonLat([18.4135, 43.8558])
    ),
  });
  vectorSource.addFeature (marker2);

var markerVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource,
});
map.addLayer(markerVectorLayer);
    </script>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="cards">
  <div class="container">
    <p>cards work!</p>
    <div class="container">
   <div class="col s12 m7">
     <div class="card small">
       <div class="card-image">
         <img src="images/sample-1.jpg">
         <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
       </div>
       <div class="card-content">
         <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
         I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
       </div>
       <div class="card-action">
         <a href="#">This is a link</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col s12 m7">
     <div class="card small">
       <div class="card-image">
         <img src="images/sample-1.jpg">
         <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
       </div>
       <div class="card-content">
         <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
         I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
       </div>
       <div class="card-action">
         <a href="#">This is a link</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col s12 m7">
     <div class="card small">
       <div class="card-image">
         <img src="images/sample-1.jpg">
         <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
       </div>
       <div class="card-content">
         <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
         I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
       </div>
       <div class="card-action">
         <a href="#">This is a link</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</template>

<template name="display">
  <div class="container">
    {{#if currentUser}}
    <h1>Smart Bins</h1>
    <a href="/addForm" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light cyan"><i class="material-icons left">add</i></a>
  <ul class="collection">
    {{#each notes}}
    <li class="collection-item cyan">
      {{text}}
      <a href="#" class="delete-note secondary-content btn-floating btn-small red"><i class="material-icons left">delete</i></a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  {{else}}
  <p>Please log in</p>
     <!-- kartice iz cards -->
     {{> cards}}
  {{/if}}
</div>
</template>

<template name="displayWithoutAdd">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Smart Bins</h1>
    {{#if currentUser}}
  <!--  <a href="/addForm" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light red"><i class="material-icons left">add</i></a> -->
  <ul class="collection">
    {{#each notes}}
    <li class="collection-item cyan">
      {{text}}
      <a href="#" class="delete-note secondary-content btn-floating btn-small red"><i class="material-icons left">delete</i></a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  {{else}}
  <p>Please log in</p>
  {{/if}}
</div>
</template>

<template name="testnavbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="/" class="brand-logo">Waste Manager</a>
        <a href="/maps" class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light green"><i class="material-icons left">map</i></a>
        {{> loginButtons}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footerCustom">
    <p>Zijah Mahmutbegovic, SSST 2020</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Have you enabled inline scripts? By default they are disabled in Blaze.

Comment: Apply a background color to body?